# Type Checking in PHP?

Tags: php, sublimetext

First of all, I'm not sure if 'Type Checking' is what i'm after, but i'll explain:

In Android Studio, when I'm referencing a function it'll come up and show me what's required while I'm typing it.  Now I know Android Studio is specifically built for Java and it's aware of all the project files in the current project etc.  But Is there anything available for PHP like this?

Here is an example from Android Studio:

[image]

Currently I'm using sublime, but I can't find a plugin that will something like this (probably because I'm searching for the wrong thing).

Can anyone help / point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: PHPStorm is the way to go for IDE - as it stands is this not a recommendation question -> thus, off-topic?

Comment: In addition to the comment above. If you are a student, PHPStorm offers free student pack: https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Comment: For freebies: Netbeans'll do it if you use [PHPDoc](http://docs.phpdoc.org/) comments - but that's partway through being migrated to Apache. Weirdly Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is free, supports PHP and isn't terrible...